# how to use if else with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following command:

```
df1['parent'] = df1['x'].map(lambda x: x.split('by')[1])
```

and I get:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For some of the values in the column,there is nothing after the "by", how I can do something like: if there is nothing after by then write ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) which return `NaN` if no value, so then add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['ddbytrr','df']})
print (df1)
         x
0  ddbytrr
1       df

df1['parent'] = df1['x'].str.split('by').str[1].fillna('')
print (df1)
         x parent
0  ddbytrr    trr
1       df
```

Solution with `map` and `if-else`, but it only works if no `NaN`s values in column:

```
df1['parent'] = df1['x'].map(lambda x: x.split('by')[1] if len(x.split('by')) > 1 else '')
print (df1)
         x parent
0  ddbytrr    trr
1       df
```

What is same as [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) solution:

```
splitted = df1['x'].str.split('by')
df1['parent'] = np.where(splitted.str.len() > 1, splitted.str[1], '')
print (df1)
         x parent
0  ddbytrr    trr
1       df
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer